# Generate presigned s3 Url for DELETE operation

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hi I'm generating the s3 presigned "GET" urls to display images using code modified from https://gist.github.com/kelvinmo/d78be66c4f36415a6b80

Ideally I should also be able to generate a presigned delete URL, put it in the browser and the image would get deleted.

I would like to modify this for the delete operation, there seems to be no info online on how to do this with a presigned url aside from the aws docs which are vague but say it's possible. I haven't managed to find any online tutorials using presigned urls for delete.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectDELETE.html

I tried just changing the Get to Delete in the request as many docs say but this creates an incorrect signature:

SignatureDoesNotMatchThe request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method

It looks like the s3 is matching the DELETE signature with PUT signature and saying it doesn't match, so how to do a delete?!

Any clues or links would be helpful. I'm assuming the current GET script is sending the wrong parameters or something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Operations on Objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectOperations.html)

Pre-signed URL is supported for:

- GET
- PUT

It is not supported for:

- LIST
- COPY
- DELETE

The reason you are getting `SignatureDoesNotMatch` is the operation is part of the signature. You cannot change the operation from GET to DELETE and expect the signature to match.

Comment: Oh that makes sense, thanks! This means I'm stuck with having to use the API just for delete?! Bummer.

Comment: Maybe that changed meanwhile, but you can also delete files now with presigned urls: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlDelete.html

Answer (score 0):

## Use the Authorization Header

This wouldn't be a URL that you can share, but it would probably accomplish your intent of being able to perform an operation via simple tools.

According to the AWS docs, you can do this with the correct authorization header:

```
            DELETE /my-second-image.jpg HTTP/1.1
            Host: bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
            Date: Wed, 12 Oct 2009 17:50:00 GMT
            Authorization: authorization string
            Content-Type: text/plain
```

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_DeleteObject.html

In this case, the header you need to set is, more or less, the pre-signed URL:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html

TODO: I'll be back with more info when I figure it out...